# How do I get information from a table into variables while using BeautifulSoup 4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I have a table, found below and stored as "table". It contains the following:

http://pastebin.com/aBFLpU4U

My code captures the correct information, but I need to know how to get each piece of the information into it's own variable. I appreciate any help with this, I have only been playing with BeautifulSoup for a week so forgive me. I have looked all over stack and haven't found an answer that works for me.

This is the output I see: http://pastebin.com/fiYQvBix

```
import sys, locale, os, re, urllib2
import lxml.etree, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bSoup

# Website that we are scraping:
BASE_URL = 'https://www.biddergy.com/detail.asp?id='

#ID = raw_input("Enter listing #: ")
ID = str(330998) # defined constant for debugging
# Store response in soup:
response  = requests.get(BASE_URL+ID)
soup = bSoup(response.text)

# Find auction info <table>
table = soup.find('table', cellpadding="2")

#### Everything above this line works great ####

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    for col in row.find_all("td"):
        print(col.string)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have figured it out.

```
data = []
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    for cols in row.find_all('td', text=True)
        for col in cols:
            data.append(col.strip())
```

Then data can be extracted from the data[] list and saved into the respective variables.

Thank you for all who have read my question!